# continuity of the derivative under certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

I am working on this exercise in a book which asks to prove that $f$ is differentiable if $f$ is continuous and that $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow x_0} f'(x)$ exists.

I know that this is easy to show using the Mean Value Theorem.

Now the problem asks: what can be said about the continuity of $f'$?

Well since $f$ is differentiable, I only have to show that $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow x_0} f'(x)=f'(x_0)$. But ideas how to proceed elude me a bit. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Oh shoot...didn't realize how easy this was. The previous problem in this book showed how to prove half of it and I didn't realize till I read the comments below. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(pppqqq's answer is correct, although I found the way it was written slightly confusing.  What follows amounts to the same proof.)

This is Theorem 5.31 in [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf).  I learned it from Spivak's *Calculus*.  Since I have not seen the result in other standard texts, I call it "a theorem of Spivak", although this is almost certainly not correct.  If someone can tell me something about the provenance of this result I will be grateful.

**Remark**: The way the question is phrased is a little strange to me.  If in fact you knew that $f$ was differentiable at $x_0$ as claimed, one can apply Darboux's Theorem (a.k.a. the Intermediate Value Theorem for Derivatives): this is in fact Theorem 5.30 in the aforelinked notes.  Namely, no derivative can have a "simple discontinuity".  However, in the setting of this problem I don't actually know how to prove that $f'(x_0)$ exists without showing at the same time that $f'(x_0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f'(x)$.

Comment: :-) I got more obscure while trying to be clearer. DonAntonio's answer is much more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

You can use l'Hospital by continuity of $\,f\,$ at $\,x_0\,$:

$$f'(x_0):=\lim_{x\to\ x_o}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)$$

since you know the rightmost limit exists (finitely, I suppose), the limit defining the leftmost term exists (finitely), and this says $\,f'(x_0)\,$ exists.

Comment: +1: This is nice!  I don't think I've seen it before.  (When you apply L'Hopital in a theoretical context, you need to be *very* careful that the fine print is in place -- I've seen many false uses of it -- but this absolutely works.)

Comment: When I read Spivak's proof of this theorem (which, btw, neither do know where it comes from) I didn't like that much the use of the MVT and that "suspicious" $$c_x\xrightarrow[x\to a]{}x$$ though I understood the fact. I came up with the above proof, and I'm sure it isn't original as I think it is not only pretty elementary but also pretty straightforward.

Comment: You can see that in my writeup I am a bit more careful about this than Spivak (although I stopped short of writing $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s: it would have been too much, I think), even to the extent of taking the limit one side at a time.

Comment: About MVT, I'm not sure I understand your objection: the proof of L'Hopital uses the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem, so the technology there is slightly higher.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I thought this was quite well-known: the standard exercise you get in an analysis class after learning about L'Hopital. It's also on the wikipedia page.

Comment: @wild: I just looked and didn't find this result in Rudin's *Principles*, for instance.  I would be interested if you can cite other sources which give it (especially since one of them may have more information).  It's interesting that it appears in the wikipedia article on L'Hopital (added on May 25 of this year).  Of course not everything that appears on wikipedia is well-known (e.g. their article on Dedekind domains contains a reference to a not well-known paper of mine), but things which are on wikipedia become better known.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I can cite one source which gives it, namely [Exercise 6.4](http://www.math.uu.nl/people/ban/lecnotes/inlanopg2013.pdf) of the lecture notes used at my (former) university. (I am not sure how helpful it'll be since it's in Dutch.)

Comment: Of course my reasoning is not that everything in the curriculum at some university, or on wikipedia, is well-known, but since *well-known* is not really well-defined it wouldn't be an interesting discussion anyway.

Comment: @wild: Thanks, and I agree.  I am not trying to debate whether this fact is well-known for exactly the reasons you suggest.  But I would be curious to know more about the history of this result.  In particular, sources from texts older than Spivak's would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have proved that $f'(x_0)$ exists and that $f'(x)\rightarrow f'(x_0)$ as $x\rightarrow x_0$. This means exactly that $f'$ is continuous at $x_0$.

**Existence of $f'(x_0)$**. I assume that $f'$ exists in a neighborhood of $x_0$, excluded $x_0$ at most. Let $\ell$ be the limit of $f'$ in $x_0$. Choose $\varepsilon >0$ and $\delta>0$ such that: $$|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f'(x)-\ell|< \varepsilon. $$
By the Mean Value Theorem, you have  $$|\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-\ell|=|f'(t)-\ell|$$
for some $t$ beetween $x$ and $x_0$. Since $|t-x_0|<|x-x_0|<\delta$, it follows that  $$|\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-\ell|<\varepsilon$$ for all $x$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$. This proves that $f'(x_0)$ exists and, at the same time, that $f'(x_0)=\ell$, by uniqueness the of the limit.

By hypothesis you have that $f'(x)\rightarrow \ell =f'(x_0)$ as $x\rightarrow x_0$ and this is a way to say that $f'$ is continuous in $x_0$.

Comment: hello, i'm not sure by what you mean but I only know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f'(x)$ exists. How can I conclude that $f'(x) \rightarrow f'(x_0)?$

Comment: I added some explanations.